# Align the icon and text to mobile version in elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, elementor

I've designed a Light store website by using elementor. I need to arrange the features section in one line like [Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyArP.png). on mobile view [mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqHjF.png) this is the default. I tried to do it by adjusting the margin it's not working properly.
How to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on column settings as marked in the screenshot. After that assign column width to 20 as shown in the screenshot2. You have to do this for all columns but before this set mobile view in Elementor.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwqyz.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcxNV.png)